# VLC through a custom ALSA device

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, alsa

How can I make VLC playing through some of my custom ALSA devices?

I created several custom ALSA devices (for routing, amplifying, mixing and other purposes) and can use them with Mplayer without any problems, but VLC does not show them in its list of availeable ALSA devices.

Here is the list VLC shows in its settings window:
[image: List of ALSA devices in VLC]

But none of these devices is from my *~/.asoundrc* file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify only by manually changing this on configuration file.

*~/.config/vlc/vlcrc*
(*[alsa]* section):

```
alsa-audio-device=upmix4
alsa-audio-channels=4
```

Something works, but other I can't get to work, for example I can't get to work vlc → alsaequal.

for test if will work you can set in command line, for instance:

```
vlc -A alsa --alsa-audio-device upmix4
```

**Edit:**

get vlc to work over alsaequal, only need uses upmix plugin (alsaequal is with 4 channels)